# Связь в бд между 2 юзерами

Tags: java, mysql

У меня есть пользователь1 в бд, у которого есть эдакая репутация. Как сохранять то, что пользователь2 уже добавил репутацию пользователю1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создадим таблицу **user_reputations** с полями:

- id: int (id записи)
- user_id: int (id пользователя - кто добавил репутацию)
- target_id: int (id пользователя - кому добавили репутацию)

Можно добавить уникальный составной индекс: **[user_id, terget_id]**

При добавлении рейтинга проверяешь наличие записи в таблице **user_reputations** по уникальности полей **user_id** - **target_id**.

Если нету, то создаешь запись в **user_reputations** и добавляешь рейтинг пользователю **target**.

Хотя рейтинг можно считать с помощью **count()** по записям в **user_reputations**. Но тогда в индексе поля местами поменять надо: **[terget_id, user_id]**

Comment: Спасибо, искал совсем иное решение, и не увидел очевидного :D

Comment: Надобность в синтетическом первичном ключе - весьма сомнительна. Индекс, предложенный как уникальный, в качестве первичного более перспективен...